# kotlin android. Assert assertEquals widtch Pair.Failed test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, kotlin

I test my object.Test Failed, why?
I assumed that the pairs (null, null) are as if equal to each other (according to the laws of logic, so to speak). (null, null) the same value.

Cod:

```
@Test
fun parseFullNameTest(){
    /* skillBranch tests */
    assertEquals(null to null, Utils.parseFullName(null))
```

Error:

> ```
> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
> Expected :(null, null)
> Actual   :(null, null)
> <Click to see difference>
>
>
>   at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:57)
>   at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:329)
>   at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:78)
>   at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:86)
>   at ru.skillbranch.devintensive.UnitTest.parseFullNameTest(UnitTest.kt:35)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>
> Process finished with exit code -1
> ```

how it works?!

Comment: Utils.parseFullName(null) probably doesn't return null to null, but null to someObjectWhoseToStringReturnsNull. Use your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

What the error message shows is that *the string representation* (result of calling `toString()`) of `Utils.parseFullName(null)` is `(null, null)`. This doesn't mean `Utils.parseFullName(null)` is actually `Pair(null, null)`; it could be e.g. `Pair("null", "null")`. Without showing `parseFullName`'s code I don't think it's possible to be more precise.